# Tweetstream Gem: Change tracking keywords

Tags: rubygems, tweetstream

I am using the gem [Tweetstream](https://github.com/tweetstream/tweetstream) to access the twitter streaming API. Currently I am wondering what would be the correct way to change the tracked keywords. The user of my application can provide new keywords to be tracked at any time. My first idea is to just stop the tracking daemon and afterwards restart it with the new keywords. Not sure if this is a good solution though.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Nils

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one?